# I was able to search for the word and print the grid with dots and word but there is a extra line of dots in printing after it

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I have a text file of grid of letters from where I have to find a word
such as

odsdsnslryy

ecajjgigqgy

fqlzfbzedme

wqogkvatqjh

lsjmvdkmqlu

rhnrbzrnfcg

euxwmyleqei

ezzamtwmgst

examplejpzh

fkhygikqjuc

igzynopmxrc

faexqjljvom

wtxtehloipx

example

I have to find the word example from the grid and reprint the grid with the word such as

[image]

The code I wrote was able to print it however the line of dots after the line with word is printing beside that rather than printing it after the line finish.

the code i wrote

```
row_num = len(grid)
col_num = len(grid[0])
for elem in grid:
    for word in words:
        if word not in elem:
            print(col_num * '.')
        else:
            len_word = len(word)
            for i in range(len(elem)):
                if elem[i:len_word] == word:
                    print(word, end = '')
                else:
                    print('.', end = '')
```

and it's printing is

[image]

Also please let me know what change I have to make if I want to search the word from right to left

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Where `sample.txt` is the "grid" of words copied as-is from your question.

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    word = "example"
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    longest_line = len(max(lines))

    grid = "\n".join(
        "." * len(line) if word not in line
        else f"{word}{'.' * (longest_line - len(word))}"
        for line in lines
    )

    print(grid)
```

Output:

```
...........

...........

...........

...........

...........

...........

...........

...........

example....

...........

...........

...........

...........
```

Comment: Can you check what I did wrong in my code?